# Using nginx to redirect '/blog' to wordpress website hosted on another instance

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a website and want to host a wordpress blog(hosted on a different instance) under '/blog'. 
I am using nginx proxy with below configuration

```
location ^~ /blog
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   Host                 $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy        true;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass         11.111.11.111
    proxy_redirect     off;
  }
```

I have also modified wordpress settings->general

WordPress Address (URL) - http://mywebsite.com/blog

Site Address (URL) - http://mywebsite.com/blog

The '/blog' in not fully functional as it is unable to load css and js .

Anyone has any idea how to do this. I have read many posts on this issue , but none solved my issue. 
Thanks.

Comment: Is the blog hosted in the root of the other instance?

Comment: yes , its hosted on root of other instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably missing a mapping from the public URI `/blog` to the upstream URI `/`.

You can perform this function using the `location` and `proxy_pass` directives by appending a URI in the `proxy_pass` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details. For example:

```
location ^~ /blog/ {
    proxy_pass http://192.0.2.0/;
}
```

Depending on your overall configuration, the above may prevent the URL `//example.com/blog` (i.e. without a trailing `/`) from being correctly forwarded, in which case either (1) add a specific location block to handle the single case, or (2) add a `rewrite ... break` to the location block above.

Option (1) example (added to above):

```
location = /blog { rewrite ^ /blog/ last; }
```

Option (2) example:

```
location ^~ /blog {
    rewrite ^/blog(?:/(.*))?$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://192.0.2.0;
}
```

In this second option, the aliasing function is moved to the `rewrite` statement, and the `proxy_pass` has no URI appended. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: Sorry for late reply @RichardSmith. I tried your second method and it worked but some of the internal links are not working properly like
1) **/wp-admin/post.php**: instead publishing post ,its  _redirecting_  to  **/wp-admin/edit.php**
2)Also **wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category** : is _redirecting_ to **/wp-admin/edit-tags.php**

Don't know why its causing redirection ?